# Multiple Layout files in node.js express framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have setup a project in node with the express framework. I like that it allows me to create a layout with a file called "layout" in the views directory. But what if I want to have multiple layout files? I don't see an option for that. Does anyone know a way?

Maybe something like:

```
res.render('report', {
        title: 'My report',
        layoutfile: 'mylayout'
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`layout` is what you're looking for :)

```
res.render('report', {
       title : 'My report'
    , layout : 'mylayout'
});
```

Assuming that the file matches the engine you're using.  If not, you need to tack on the extension, e.g. `layout.jade`

Comment: wow... I feel a little stupid. In the docs it says you can set layout:false, but it didn't mention you could put in a different name altogether. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I just looked - actually it does, scroll down a few more lines :)

Comment: Well what do you know. It sure is. All this trouble because I can't read... Thanks for the answer anyway :-)